# ng serve cannot find node.js core modules

Tags: angular, angular7

When I run

```
ng serve --watch
```

I get these build errors:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/fb-wars/node_modules/forever-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/http-signature/lib/signer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/fb-wars/node_modules/http-signature/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/fb-wars/node_modules/request'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/fb-wars/node_modules/tunnel-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/fb-wars/node_modules/forever-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/fb-wars/node_modules/request'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/fb-wars/node_modules/tunnel-agent'
```

all the errors relate to not being able to find node.js core module definitions, this seems pretty weird especially considering I have node types installed:

```
{
  "name": "fb-wars",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "fb": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@types/fb": "0.0.23",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^11.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

anybody know what might be going on?

Here is what `ng --version` says:

```
   _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 11.3.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.1.4
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.4
@ngtools/webpack                  7.1.4
@schematics/angular               7.1.4
@schematics/update                0.11.4
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.23.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's because I installed the facebook package 'fb', which uses some core node.js modules in it. I want to use that package in the browser, not sure if it will work yet, but to ignore those modules in the browser build, you would put this in `package.json`:

```
  "browser": {
    "http": false,
    "https": false,
    "net": false,
    "path": false,
    "stream": false,
    "tls": false,
    "zlib": false,
    "crypto": false,
    "fs": false
  },
```

yeah that didn't work, apparently need install a different JS sdk than the one on NPM named 'fb', currently am trying to figure out how to install:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart
```